# How to make the Feedback Assistant app visible in the Launchpad?

Tags: mojave, launchpad

I can open the Feedback assistant app from the path `/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Feedback Assistant.app` but it is not visible in the Launchpad in Mojave 10.14.6 .

How do I make it visible and open it directly from the Launchpad rather than having to pin it onto the Dock?

Comment: Feedback Assistant does show in my LaunchPad, but I have it in my Dock as well. It's possible that having it in the Dock will also put in Launchpad. Whether LaunchPad will 'remember' it if you remove the app from the Dock afterwards, is something you could try.

Comment: @benwiggy the Launchpad does not "remember" the application even if it is pinned to the dock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place an *alias* of the **Feedback Assistant** in the, e.g., **Applications** folder in **Finder**, it will show in **Launchpad**, without having to pin it to the **Dock**.

In **Finder**, navigate to, or use: **Go** > **Go to Folder…**

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications
```

Select the **Feedback Assistant** app and then drag and drop while pressing **⌥⌘** to the **Applications** folder to create an alias.

**Feedback Assistant** will now appear in **Launchpad**.

---

Note that while it will now appear on the last screen of **Launchpad** nonetheless, it can be dragged and dropped to where you'd like it on the screen or different screen.

Comment: This solution works but weirdly if you open an alias link from the Launchpad the application launches but the application windows does not appear. You need to manually click on the dock icon to open the window on top of any existing windows. Simply copy pasting the entire application in the applications folder instead of creating an alias solved the issue.

Comment: @Kewal Shah, When I click the _alias_ of **Feedback Assistant** from **Launchpad**, the **Welcome to Feedback Assistant** sign in window is front and center, without having to click its **Dock Tile**.

Comment: Yes, I stand corrected. It takes a while to open for my MacOS. I guess I just did not wait.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications`.
2. Copy the **Feedback Assistant** app using <kbd>⌘</kbd> +
   <kbd>C</kbd>.
3. Paste it in the **Applications** folder <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

Viola! Now when you click on the **Feedback Assistant** app from the Launchpad the application will open immediately.

Comment: Don't do this. Then you have a duplicated Feedback Assistent. After an OS upgrade, you have two different versions of the App in two different places, leading to a lot of issues. Just put an alias into the /Applications folder (CMD+OPT while dragging the App).